# Dickey - Fuller - Hasza Test

Tags: time-series

I would like to ask whether the series must be stationary in order to conduct the Dickey Fuller Hasza seasonal stationarity test.

Comment: This feels like you might be asking the wrong question because the answer is obviously no. If the series was required to be stationary, what would you be testing?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find online, the Dickey-Fuller-Hasza test tests the null hypothesis of a seasonal unit root (i.e., non-stationarity). Rejection of this hypothesis implies stationarity. So no, your sample does not have to be stationary. You can find out if it is stationary using this statistical test.